# I can call any method on Nil and this feels wrong

Tags: raku

I spent considerable time debugging a script recently, and when I finally found the problem it was because of code that looked like this:

```
class Foo {
    has $.bar;
    method () {
        # do stuff
        $!.bar;
    }
}
```

It turned out the problem was with that `$!.bar`, which should have been either `$!bar` or `$.bar`. I get this.

But *why doesn't this die*?

Looking at this in more detail, it looks like the issue here is that I'm trying to call a (non-existent) method `bar` on [`$!`](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/$!), which at this point is `Nil` because there haven't been any errors.

And it looks like I can actually call any method I want on `Nil` and they all silently return `Nil`, including stuff like `Nil.this-is-a-fake-method` and `Nil.reverse-entropy(123)`.

Is this a feature? If so, what's the rationale?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's intended and documented, yes. The headline for `Nil` is "Absence of a value or a benign failure", and the [class documentation](https://docs.raku.org/type/Nil) mentions

> Any method call on `Nil` of a method that does not exist, and consequently, any subscripting operation, will succeed and return `Nil`.
>
> ```
> say Nil.ITotallyJustMadeThisUp;  # OUTPUT: «Nil␤» 
> say (Nil)[100];                  # OUTPUT: «Nil␤» 
> say (Nil){100};                  # OUTPUT: «Nil␤»
> ```

[Synopsis 2](https://design.raku.org/S02.html#Nil) states "Any undefined method call on `Nil` returns `Nil`, so that `Nil` propagates down method call chains. Likewise any subscripting operation on `Nil` returns `Nil`", so the intent seems to be allowing expressions like `$foo.Bar()[0].Baz()` without requiring checks for `Nil` at every step, or special "Nil-safe" method call and subscripting operators.

Comment: Indeed.  And quite a long time ago already as well: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/174727377f (December 2013)  See also the associated speculation: https://design.raku.org/S02.html#Nil

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen ah, I think S02 has the answer. "Any undefined method call on `Nil` returns `Nil`, so that `Nil` propagates down method call chains." So it's intended that you can do `$foo.Bar().Baz().Blah()` without needing nil tests at every step or a special `?.` sort of operator (as long as you correctly handle nil at the end). I'll edit that in, thank you.

Comment: A `Nil` that doesn't error and just throws back more `Nil` gets fairly extensive use in Obj-C and the NS Frameworks where it's used in a similar way — allows for chained calls that keep passing on Nil.  I don't know the exact performance penalties of exceptions and catching them, but my guess is that the `Nil` chaining can be more efficient, if less flexible.

Comment: (but that's an entirely uninformed guess, so I'm happy for lizmat or jnthn to tell me I'm wrong and that I need to shut up :-) )

Comment: The `Nil` class has a `FALLBACK` https://docs.raku.org/language/typesystem#index-entry-FALLBACK_(method)  method, which returns `Nil`.  Basically, just before an exception is thrown because a method could not be found, a check for `FALLBACK` is done, and called if available.

Answer (score 6):

This question (and hobbs' answer) also made me feel... uneasy: I eventually found https://docs.raku.org/language/traps: it explains that assigning `Nil` produces a different value, usually `Any`. The following basic REPL interaction also demonstrates this:

```
> my $foo = Nil
(Any)

> $foo.bar
No such method 'bar' for invocant of type 'Any'
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 1

> my $bar := Nil
Nil

> $bar.baz
Nil
```

(( the difference between `=` and `:=` is covered here: https://docs.raku.org/language/containers#Binding ))

...so the general idea is that the 'absent value or benign failure' is far less widespread in regular code than I (and perhaps you as well?) suddenly feared: it does occur however, when you are going to work with regex matches *directly* and in your particular accidental situation related to directly invoking methods on `$!`.

This made me more aware about the difference between `Nil` and `Any`, and the provided rationale made more sense to me.

Comment: `Nil` sets a container to its default state. You can change the default value. `my $foo is default(42) = 5;` `$foo = Nil;` `say $foo; # 42`